# Xamarin WKWebView not opening email and tel links

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

Please excuse my newbie question, I am a very new Xamarin developer, and I don't know Swift, so answers in Swift have been usless, as I haven't been able to translate it to C#. I found some resources in Swift that were similar to this issue, but I do not know Swift, so was unable to translate the code into a xamarin solution. I was unable to get any link to work in a webpage viewed within the WKWebView that my app uses. Now, I can open links that have the "target=_blank" attribute, but I am unable to open any other link, specifically, links that open within the current window, and links that have the "mailto:" and "tel" attributes in the URL. I got the target=_blank links to work by adding the following class to the WebViewController, and a line to the ViewDidLoad method:

```
public class NavDelegate : WKUIDelegate
    {

        public override WKWebView CreateWebView(WKWebView webView, WKWebViewConfiguration configuration, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, WKWindowFeatures windowFeatures)
        {
            var url = navigationAction.Request.Url;
            if (navigationAction.TargetFrame == null)
            {
                webView.LoadRequest(navigationAction.Request);
            }


            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here is the line added to the ViewDidLoad() method: 
    WebAppView.UIDelegate = new NavDelegate();

And the complete ViewDidLoad method:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            WebViewLogo.Owner = this;

            //Check System Version and set WebView accordingly
            //WKWebView only supported on iOS Versions 11+
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
            {
                View.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 108, 1024, 611);
                View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(View, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, 1.0f, 0.0f));
                View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1.0f, 0.0f));
                View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(View, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1.0f, 0.0f));
                View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1.0f, 43.0f));

                var WebAppView = new WKWebView(View.Frame, new WKWebViewConfiguration());
                WebAppView.UIDelegate = new NavDelegate();
                View.AddSubview(WebAppView);
                //set the margins and constraints


                // Add a tap recognizer to reset timer
                var actionGestureRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer(this, new ObjCRuntime.Selector("HandleActionEvent:"));
                actionGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                actionGestureRecognizer.Delegate = new GestureDelegate();
                WebAppView.AddGestureRecognizer(actionGestureRecognizer);

                // Load the quote
                //Attempt to get the current quote if active
                var storedQuoteDataAsJson = QuoteManager.FetchQuote();

                // If quote is empty or expired pop to the contact screen
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(storedQuoteDataAsJson) || !QuoteManager.IsQuoteActive((int)NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.IntForKey("QuoteExpireTimeInSeconds")))
                {
                    AppDelegate.Self.PopToTarget(ControllerScreen.ContactController);
                }

                // Load the quote
                Quote currentQuote = QuoteManager.DeserializeQuote(storedQuoteDataAsJson);
                if (currentQuote != null)
                {
                    // NOTE: https required for iOS 9 ATS
                    var url = String.Format("{0}{1}", NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("WebURL"), currentQuote.QuoteID);
                    WebAppView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));
                }
            }
            else //UIWebView is not supported on iOS versions less than 11, so must use UIWebView
            {

                View.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 108, 1024, 611);
                View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(View, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, 1.0f, 0.0f));
                View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, 1.0f, 0.0f));
                View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(View, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, 1.0f, 0.0f));
                View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1.0f, 43.0f));
                var WebAppView = new UIWebView(View.Frame);
                View.AddSubview(WebAppView);
                //set the margins and constraints

                // Add a tap recognizer to reset timer
                var actionGestureRecognizer = new UITapGestureRecognizer(this, new ObjCRuntime.Selector("HandleActionEvent:"));
                actionGestureRecognizer.NumberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                actionGestureRecognizer.Delegate = new GestureDelegate();
                WebAppView.AddGestureRecognizer(actionGestureRecognizer);

                // Load the quote
                //Attempt to get the current quote if active
                var storedQuoteDataAsJson = QuoteManager.FetchQuote();

                // If quote is empty or expired pop to the contact screen
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(storedQuoteDataAsJson) || !QuoteManager.IsQuoteActive((int)NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.IntForKey("QuoteExpireTimeInSeconds")))
                {
                    AppDelegate.Self.PopToTarget(ControllerScreen.ContactController);
                }

                // Load the quote
                Quote currentQuote = QuoteManager.DeserializeQuote(storedQuoteDataAsJson);
                if (currentQuote != null)
                {
                    // NOTE: https required for iOS 9 ATS
                    var url = String.Format("{0}{1}", NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("WebURL"), currentQuote.QuoteID);
                    WebAppView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(url)));

                }
            }
        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: How did you solve the target _blank?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible by using [WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/WebKit.WKNavigationDelegate/)

```cs
class AllowAllDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webview, WKNavigationAction action, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> actionCallback)
    {
        // do some checks if you want to filter actions 
        actionCallback(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow);
    }
}
```

**use it**

```cs
WebAppView.NavigationDelegate = new AllowAllDelegate();
```

---

Same for UIWebView with [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIWebViewDelegate/)

```cs
class AllowAllOldDelegate : UIWebViewDelegate 
{
    public override bool ShouldStartLoad (UIWebView webView, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType) 
    {
        // do some checks if you want to filter actions 
        return true;
    }
}
```

**use it**

```cs
WebAppView.Delegate = new AllowAllOldDelegate();
```

You can also avoid creating new classes, if you use the [Weak Delegate mechanism](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events/#Strong_Delegates_vs._Weak_Delegates).

Answer (score 0):

I got the following to work.  Keep in mind my entire project is based off of [Xamarin's "HybridWebView" sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview/) with custom HybridWebViewRenderer classes for iOS and Android.  I also used the information in the original post of [this question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/118243/cannot-open-links-without-target-blank-tag-in-them?).  I did not run into the same issue that this user had though.

New class:

```
public class MyWKUIDelegate : WKUIDelegate
{
    public override WKWebView CreateWebView(WKWebView webView, WKWebViewConfiguration configuration, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, WKWindowFeatures windowFeatures)
    {
        var url = navigationAction.Request.Url;
        if (navigationAction.TargetFrame == null)
        {
            webView.LoadRequest(navigationAction.Request);
        }


        return null;
    }
}
```

Assigned my new MyWKUIDelegate to the UIDelegate property of my WKWebView instance:

```
var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };

userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, "native");
WKWebView webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
webView.UIDelegate = new MyWKUIDelegate();
```